# How can I make my image overlapping on another image responsive

Tags: css

I'm going to use images to better ask my question. I have 2 images the arrow at the bottom and the square image. Right now, [this is my page when the screen is fully maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d0oF.png). [This is when my page is resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dLmX.png). What I want to achieve is to make the arrow scalable meaning when the page is minimized, the square image resizes, the arrow resizes and looks the same as the maximized page.

```css
  .bgPic{
     position: absolute;
     background-position: center;
     object-fit: contain;
     display: inline;
    }
    .background{
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 100%; 
    }
    #resize{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    right: 27%;
    max-width: 10%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="background">
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="image" class="bgPic" width="100%" height="100%" />
        <img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/arrow-png-no-background-download-this-image-as-600.png" id="resize" alt="" width="100%" height="auto%" >
    </div>
```

Comment: The images you have shared aren't providing clear understanding of the problem. Could you further elaborate your issue. Or share the correct code.

Comment: @HusainTezabwala sorry! I have updated the code. Please try to resize the window and I think you will get what I mean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you need your main image fully visible the whole time.
Then you can fix this by removing some of your code and just adding the CSS position relative to the wrapper div with class background. This one is important because this is then the parent where you can position (absolute) your arrow to.

FYI 1: I also changed the position of the arrow to bottom & right.

FYI 2: the size of the arrow I changed to percentages so this will scale when you resize the browser (if this isn't needed you can use pixel values).

HTML

```
<div class="background">
    <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="image" class="bgPic" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/arrow-png-no-background-download-this-image-as-600.png" class="resize" alt="" width="100%" height="auto%" >
</div>
```

CSS

```
.background {
    position: relative;
}

.resize {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 5%;
}
```

For an example see https://jsfiddle.net/4mpq10ne/8/

Comment: Hi @Nick Van Loocke. So in summary, what you meant is that I should set the position of my background image to be relative and the other image elements to absolute?

Comment: Hi @assdhelppls yes but I would advice to only put position absolute on the arrow. Because your main image has a width and height of 100% so this will fill the container (div with class background). And you position the arrow image based on your container.